# MySQL Single-Query COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, count

There are so many of these questions, it's ridiculous. However, even after reading many of them, I still have come short of my wanted result.

Using, PHP, I poll MySQL database using the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(`NumRecip`) AS `Total`
FROM `Messaging`
WHERE `Type`='Response'
AND `datetime`>='2013-09-01 00:00:00'
```

I have also attempted to add `GROUP BY NumRecip` And attempted `COUNT(*)` but I get the result 55. (If you were trying this, obviously won't be the same answer). The 55 is not at all arbitrary. The 55 is the number of rows that fit this context. The answer should be somewhere between 150 and 250 (Just guessing, but whatever). I have used the `Max(NumRecip)` and resulted 66 (which is the max btw) but I want the entire total of each and every value.

Long story short... I want a query that will count all the 2s, 3s, 6s, and the one 66 and get my final answer, not the 55 (number of rows) or the 66 (max number).

All queries I attempted:

```
SELECT COUNT(`NumRecip`) AS `Total`
FROM `Messaging`
WHERE `Type`='Response'
AND `datetime`>='2013-09-01 00:00:00'
```

--

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Total`
FROM `Messaging`
WHERE `Type`='Response'
AND `datetime`>='2013-09-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY `NumRecip`
```

--

```
SELECT COUNT(`NumRecip`) AS `Total`
FROM `Messaging`
WHERE `Type`='Response'
AND `datetime`>='2013-09-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY `NumRecip`
```

--

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Total`
FROM `Messaging`
WHERE `Type`='Response'
AND `datetime`>='2013-09-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY `NumRecip`
```

--

```
SELECT MAX(`NumRecip`) AS `Total`
FROM `Messaging`
WHERE `Type`='Response'
AND `datetime`>='2013-09-01 00:00:00'
```

I can do a mass query, do a `while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){` and just keep adding the `NumRecip` to a total variable, but I am under the assumption there is a one-query option to do this, and therefor, faster way.

Comment: What do you mean by "*count all the 2s, 3s, 6s, and the one 66*"? Are you looking for the total number of recipients?

Comment: @EdGibbs Yes. If I have 2 rows with 2 recipients, 2 rows with 3, 7 with 6, and 1 of 66, I want all of those to add together to get a final answer. Not the number of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count only shows the number of rows. If you want to add up all the numbers, use SUM()

```
SELECT SUM(`NumRecip`) AS `Total`
 FROM `Messaging`
 WHERE `Type`='Response'
 AND `datetime`>='2013-09-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: It is always the easiest of answers. Makes perfect sense too. Thank you :)